# First use of TListView and TTreeView does not show data

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I have only one form in my application, where I insert a frame accordingly the user action.

This form is inserted in a TScrollBox, since it sometimes has a width bigger than the screen/window.

I have one or more TListViews on the frame, and many TEdits.

When running the application and opening any frame, one or more TListView are not filled in. By debug I see the data is pulled from the SQL. TEdits are filled in. Moving the SQL cursors gets all TEdits updated accordingly.

The closing this frame and opening again (or any other) then it start showing the data on the TListView.

I have not found any correlation that make sense. Apparently there is some kind of initialization missing. Not all TListView are empty, in some frames I have 4 or 5 of them and it show 2 with data, the others are empty.

EDIT: I have changed the title of this question, since I have noted that the problem seems not be related to the LiveBindings primarly, but seems to be related to some kind of initialization of the TListView on other lists.

I made a new test and see that TTreeView is also having the same problem, showing totally out of order the data, only at first time. If I previouslly opens something else it works fine, if I close and open the frame with the TTreeview the second time is ok.

In this image I show the TreeView messed:

[image]

It should not have all that spaces and some of the nodes are overlapped.

Comment: In order to get help we need to be able to diagnose the problem. That will require you to provide more info. How about an MCVE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I could not successfully create a MCVE for myself. I was hopping someone had the same experience and found a solution and wanted to share. There are many controls and tables and livebinding. I could not isolate yet. But since Firemonkey used to be full of these nasty bugs I wanted to ask.

Comment: nothing like a downvote to start the day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My application has only one form, and everything are frames that are created as parent of a TScrollBox.

With Delphi XE5 the issues of TScrollBox were many, I had to upgrade to XE6.

Many things start working with XE6, however there is still a little problem with TScrollBox:

There is a need to call ApplyStyleLookup, after the frame is inserted and parented to the scroll, to make the initialization. That makes the TListView and TTreeView works fine since the very first time.

```
constructor TFrameBase.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;

  Align := TAlignLayout.Left;

  Parent := AOwner as TFmxObject;

  if (AOwner is TScrollBox) then
    (AOwner as TScrollBox).ApplyStyleLookup;
end;
```

This is my frame constructor. This fixed all the problems.